# Esoteric :) Error logs in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. I have encountered 2 problems:-

**1.  As it upgraded these were the error logs produced:**

- Could not install 'network-manager-openvpu' Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
- Could not install 'geoclue-2.0' Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
- The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will now run (dpkg --config -a)
- Upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process

**2.  I cannot download anything from the shopping bag icon / software center:**

- Unable to install [put any software here] Error while installing package: Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

**Annex**

I did

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

then this

```
sudo apt install --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gdm3 (3.26.1-3ubuntu3) ...
addgroup: No GID is available in the range 100-999 (FIRST_SYS_GID - LAST_SYS_GID).
addgroup: The group `gdm' was not created.
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up geoclue-2.0 (2.4.7-1ubuntu1) ...
addgroup: No GID is available in the range 100-999 (FIRST_SYS_GID - LAST_SYS_GID).
addgroup: The group `geoclue' was not created.
dpkg: error processing package geoclue-2.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of empathy:
 empathy depends on geoclue-2.0 (>= 2.0); however:
  Package geoclue-2.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package empathy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on gdm3; however:
  Package gdm3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
 geoclue-2.0
 empathy
 ubuntu-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: That's not a log, that's the error summary, and it lacks enough information to help you. Please use a terminal and copy/paste the *complete output* of the command `sudo apt install --fix-missing`. Please use proper formatting for output (use the `{}` button when composing or editing)

Comment: @user535733 Please see Annex in original post.  Don't understand "Please use proper formatting for output (use the {} button when composing or editing)"

Comment: Your real problem seems to be `addgroup: No GID is available in the range 100-999`. Look at your /etc/groups. Do you really have 899 groups in that range? No duplicates you can (carefully, using the correct command) remove?

Comment: @jam to check how many groups your system has in the 100-999 range run `getent group | egrep [1-9][0-9][0-9] | wc -l` in a terminal. `getent` will list all groups. The `egrep` will print only lines containing 100-999. `wc` will count the lines.

Comment: @J.Starnes `sudo getent group | egrep [1-9][0-9][0-9] | wc -l` says `905`

Comment: @user535733 I looked at `/etc/groups`It shows majority are crypto named guest account sessions.  Upgrade did not clear it. Operating system doesn't have Cron [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)  to clear them?

Comment: There are 2 files: `group` and `group-`, `group` I can open in gedit, `group-` is non-opening

Comment: @J.Starnes Checkout my comments to your answer below.

Comment: @J.Starnes https://askubuntu.com/questions/979467/esoteric-error-logs-in-ubuntu-17-10#comment1574483_979677

Comment: @J.Starnes Could you take a look at my /etc/groups file please and tell me what code entries I should put on terminal because I don't want to ruin my system, thank you https://askubuntu.com/questions/979467/esoteric-error-logs-in-ubuntu-17-10#comment1577906_979677

Comment: @J.Starnes How do I put your bash script in Answer Section into terminal, I copy/pasted it into terminal and it all came up permission denied? Do I need to put `sudo` first rather than shebang et al?

Answer (score 0):

## Remove some unneeded groups

### Step 1 - Full system backup

**The commands in this answer can cause havoc with your system.** Make a full system backup with your preferred method. Validate/test this backup. Secure your backups so that the following steps can not harm them.
For more information about backups see [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommunityHelpWiki) - [BackupYourSystem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem). I would recommend [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) for a one time full os and user data backup. But for on going backups I use [Borg Backup](https://www.borgbackup.org/).

### Step 2 - Select groups and users to remove

Running `getent group | egrep \:[1-9][0-9][0-9]\:` will list groups in the 100-999 range. From this list take note of a minimum of 10 unwanted groups related to guest accounts. They should not have any users listed as part of the group, nor should they be programs that are currently installed. The following code block shows that fourth field contains users in that group. Of these few only sambashare has a user. Only the "guest-" groups are a problem.

```
saned:x:122:
uuidd:x:123:
sambashare:x:124:jon
ssh:x:125:
geoclue:x:126:
guest-262uVu:x:127:
guest-qAD7pX:x:128:
guest-H1HJgy:x:129:
guest-fbfgab:x:130:
guest-LdeNZx:x:131:
guest-jIHtqC:x:132:
guest-w7GINW:x:133:
```

### Step 3 - Remove unwanted groups

In the following commands replace `<NEWGID>` with a group to hold any residual files. You could either use an existing group or a new group. Also replace `<OLDGID>` with a group to be deleted. Run the commands once for each group to be removed. If you don't want any of the files from the old groups run the potentially very harmful command `find / -group <OLDGID> -exec rm {} \;`. If you don't care who may end up owning the deleted groups files you could just run `delgroup --only-if-empty <OLDGID>`.

```
find / -group <OLDGID> -exec rm {} \;
find / -group <OLDGID> -exec chgrp -h <NEWGID> {} \;
delgroup --only-if-empty <OLDGID>
# example using random groups
find / -group 200 -exec chgrp -h 2000 {} \;
delgroup --only-if-empty 200
```

### Step 4 - Clean up

Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to finish configuring unpacked packages.

A bash script covering steps 2-4. Open a text editor, copy and past the following code block. Save the file as `guest.sh`. In a terminal navigate to where `guest.sh` was saved. run `chmod +x guest.sh`, to make the file executable. Then run `./guest.sh`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
TEMP=$(mktemp --tmpdir)

getent group | grep guest- | cut --delimiter=: -f 3 > "$TEMP"

NGID=$(head -n1 "$TEMP")
GIDS=$(grep -v "$NGID" "$TEMP" | tr '\n' ' ')

for i in $GIDS
    do
        find / -group "$i" -exec chgrp -h "$NGID" {} \;
        delgroup --only-if-empty "$i"
    done
rm "$TEMP"
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Thanks this is superb.  Please tell me about `replace <NEWGID> with a group to hold any residual files` - should this be a new group or existing group.  What command should I use if I don't want a  group to hold any residual files - could I use only `delgroup --only-if-empty <OLDGID>`?

Comment: *Make a full system backup with your preferred method. Validate/test this backup. Secure your backups so that the following steps can not harm them*.  **==** What do you suggest if I am novice?  Should I also use manual USB if backup file cannot be located?

Comment: What does this mean `find / -group 200 -exec chgrp -h 2000 {} \;
delgroup --only-if-empty 200`?

Comment: The first line is an example of using `find` files owned by gid 200 in the path `/` then for every file found execute `chgrp`. `chgrp` changes the file to be owned by gid 2000. The second line runs `delgrop` to delete the 200 group but only if it has no users in it. The groups used in the above commands were chosen at random just to be used as an example.

Comment: /etc/groups file [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tVVy7YgjnmbwQQ8kBwO4PdXGkyH9TnH1v3r8-S_-hcg/edit?usp=sharing)